# How to override transaction timeout value for Spring JDBCTemplate during batchUpdate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am calling batch batchUpdate which usually sends more than 50 queries in one call and each update query can potentially update 10,000 records. This entire process is taking time and eventually failing with transaction timeout exception.
The data source which is defined in springContext.xml is injected to JdbcTemplate through @Qualifier, the transaction timeout which is defined in the springContext.xml is applicable to the entire application, but in this particular transaction I would like to override the transaction timeout value before calling batchUpdate method.

```
@Qualifier("myDataSource")
  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) {
    this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    jdbc.setFetchSize(10000);
    jdbc.setQueryTimeout(0); // zero means there is no limit
  }

  //I want to set custom transaction timeout before calling this from some other methods.
  jdbc.batchUpdate(queries.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Transactional` annotation to specify the timeout.

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(timeout = 123) // 123 sec
```

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-attransactional-settings) is the reference documentation.

Comment: you mean on top of the method where I am calling jdbc.batchUpdate(queries.toArray(new String[0]));? Currently this method is not marked with @Transactional annotation at all, still the entire batchUpdate is being execute under a transaction, I wonder, how it is happening.

Comment: I still get transaction timeout even after setting it for 5 minutes (300 seconds), the problem seems to be there is a deadlock occurring due to the fact that my transaction has select pick rows to be updated by update query, I tried SELECT FOR UPDATE which also did not work because my select query has aggregate function. is there any other way to tell my transaction not to lock rows during select?